# Using my contract method for ERC20 token transfer and setting initial owner

Tags: web3js, tokens, erc-20

I know this has been asked before in a couple of places, but I haven't progressed since a day. I have the following code to set the initial owner of my ERC20 token. I use the following code in a POST method, where the user would input their address and I would set them as an owner.

I have deployed the contract using Metamask and the "from" account is the same from which I have deployed it from.
The testSendAccount is basically a placeholder I use. Is there anything more I should have added in the code?

The code is the following:

```
'use strict';
/*
const config = require('../config');
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
const infuraApi = require('infura')(config.infuraApiKey);
//Set a provider (HttpProvider)
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/' + infuraApi));
}

const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var accountAddressHex = require('metamaskAccount')(config.metamaskAccount.metamaskAddressHex);
var accountAddressPrivateKey  = require('metamaskAccount')(config.metamaskAccount.metamaskAddressPrivateKey);
var privateKey = new Buffer(accountAddressPrivateKey, 'hex')
var count = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddressHex);
var contractAddress = require('solidityContract')(config.solidityContract.contractAddress);
var contractAbiArray = require('solidityContract')(config.solidityContract.contractABI);
var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbiArray).at(contractAddress );

const testSendAccount= [Redacted];
const gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
const gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(gasPrice);
const gasLimitHex = web3.toHex(3000000);
//const tokenTransferAmount = 1;//EDIT 1

var tokenIdToAssignHex = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.sendTransaction( {from: accountAddressHex}, function(err, hash){
        if(!err) { tokenIdToAssignHex = hash;
        console.log(tokenIdToAssignHex); }
        else { console.log("Error"); }
      });


 var tokenIdToAssign = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.call(function(err, res){
          if(!err) { tokenIdToAssign = res;
            console.log(tokenIdToAssign.toNumber()); }
        else { console.log("Error"); }
      });

var rawTransaction = {
    "from": accountAddressHex,
    "nonce": web3.toHex(count),
    "gasPrice": gasPriceHex,
    "gasLimit": gasLimitHex,
    "to": contractAddress,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contract.setInitialOwner.getData(testSendAccount, tokenTransferAmount, {from: accountAddressHex}), //contract.transfer.getData("0xCb...", 10, {from: "0x26..."}),
    "chainId": 0x03 //Ropsten id is 3, replace with 1 for main
};
var tx = new EthereumTx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privateKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
    if (!err) { console.log( 'contract creation tx: ' + hash); }
    else {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
});
```

**EDIT 1**
I have changed, `const tokenTransferAmount = 1;` to `const tokenIdToAssign = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.call();` since this is the variable that takes care of which should be the next token to be set in the contract.

**EDIT 2**
I have changed the tokenToAssign and added the

`var tokenIdToAssignHex = contract.nextTokenIdToAssign.sendTransaction( {from: accountAddressHex}, function(err, hash){
    if(!err) { tokenIdToAssignHex = hash;
    console.log(tokenIdToAssignHex); }
    else { console.log("Error"); }
  });`

**EDIT 3**
**EDIT 1**

Here is the contract code for the setInitialOwner:

```
function setInitialOwner(address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public
    onlyOwner
    tokensRemainingToAssign
    tenKLimit (_tokenId)
    yesZeroAddressOwner (_tokenId) 
    notSelfSend (_to, _tokenId) {

        tokenIdToOwner[_tokenId] = _to;
        balanceOfAddress[_to] = balanceOfAddress[_to].add(1);
        emit Assign(_to, _tokenId);

        tokenIndexArray.push(_tokenId);

        uint256 length = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        ownedTokensIndexMapping[_tokenId] = length;
        addressToTokenIdByIndex[msg.sender][length] = _tokenId;

        nextTokenIdToAssign = nextTokenFunc(nextTokenIdToAssign);
       hypeKillsTokensRemainingToAssign = tokensRemainingToAssign.sub(1);
        }
```

Comment: Is your code working? If not, what's going wrong?

Comment: The code is not working. My idea was that after the code execution, the toAccount would be able to see the token in the Metamask wallet, once I add the token in the UI. But this seems not the case.  Also I have edited, a line in the code, to get the nextTokenId. This ID we should use during the transfer to know exactly what number we are sending, but when I to console.log() its value, I get "undefined".

Comment: So, one thing I tried to do was `web3.eth.getCode(contractAddress);`which yield a null. This is odd, since I deployed the contract using Metamask on the ropsten network.

Comment: Do you have a transaction id? Does the transaction completes with succeed status? Does your ERC20 generates a Tranfer event?

Comment: I was able to make one transaction. But I cannot manage to update the nextTokenToAssign with the `tokenIdToAssignHex`in order to updata the  next token id. So I end up with token 1, which will revert any further transaction. I have added the tokenIdToAssignHex, but it yields an error.

Comment: I made an edit, adding the contract code. So, in order to update my `nextTokenIdToAssign` I had to send a rawTransaction again to `nextTokenIdToAssign`, since infura does not support sendTransaction. The problem at this point it is still not updating. Could it be caused be the setter function `nextTokenFunc(uint256 _tokenId)`, taking into account that `nextTokenIdToAssign` is essentially changed during setInitialOwner with an internal function like `nextTokenIdToAssign`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since others may encounter this problem, I will post the solution I arrived at. The problem here was that my `nextTokenToAssign` variable was not updating properly.

I used [myetherwallet.com][1] to deploy the contract and to check its value. When I deployed the contract, if afterwards I did not call the constructor function, setting the initial value of `nextTokenToAssign` to 1, it would not update during the successive call to the `setInitialOwner` function. So the solution simply was to simply call the function.

Answer (score 1):

web3 1.0 API change.

```
let myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress);
let data = myContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, value).encodeABI();
let rawTx = {
    "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
    "gasPrice": "0x3b9aca00",
    "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
    "to": contractAddress,
    "value": "0x00",
    "data": data,
}
const tx = new Tx(rawTx)
tx.sign(privateKey)
let serializedTx = "0x" + tx.serialize().toString('hex');
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx).on('transactionHash', function (txHash) {

}).on('receipt', function (receipt) {
    console.log("receipt:" + receipt);
}).on('confirmation', function (confirmationNumber, receipt) {
    //console.log("confirmationNumber:" + confirmationNumber + " receipt:" + receipt);
}).on('error', function (error) {

});
```

you can see this:  [Transferring ERC20 tokens from account using web3 over Ropsten](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1151)

Comment: Thanks for the web3 1.0 API change tip. I will have to eventually upgrade to 1.0 too.